# Supersized Slide - go to specific Slide by Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, supersized

Hi guys I am using the Superslide slider for fullscreen slider images. Now i want to to create a website with nearly no text. So by using the main mavigation, it just should change the images in the slider, or jump to a specific image in the slider.

I have tried to use the api.goTo() call in a js function, but it always get me an error,

> Cannot GET /linoSlider/showSlideTwo()

and also the posts on the internet didn't help me.

Any ideas how tu jump to a specific image using the supersized slider?

Answer (score 0):

To jump to a specific slide you should use a jquery click action in your menu and the api.goTo() including the image number, you should keep track of the number by yourself.

```
<a href="#" class="link_class01"><span>Menu Item 1</span></a>
<a href="#" class="link_class02"><span>Menu Item 2</span></a>

$(".link_class01").click(function(){
api.goTo(1);
});
$(".link_class02").click(function(){
api.goTo(2);
});
```

Try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your main html doc. 
The links will be url/doc.html?num=2

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}



jQuery(function($){
    var slideNum = GetURLParameter("num");
    var num = 1;
    if(slideNum!=null){
        if(num > 0) num = slideNum;
    }
}
```

This was such a pain in the a** i hope this helps.